# Bidirectional GRU with 2x2 inputs

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I am builduing a network, that splits strings into words, words into characters, embeds each character and then computes a vector represenation of this string by aggregating characters into words and words into string. Aggregation is performed with bidirectional gru layer with attention.
To test this thing, let's say I am interested in 5 words and 5 characters in this string. In this case my transformation is:

```
["Some string"] -> ["Some","strin","","",""] -> 
["Some_","string","_____","_____","_____"] where _ is the padding symbol ) -> 
[[1,2,3,4,0],[1,5,6,7,8],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]] (shape 5x5)
```

Next I have an embedding layer that turns every character into an embedding vector of length, let's say 6. So my feature becomes a 5x5x6 matrix. Then I pass this output to bidirectional gru layer and perform some other manipulations that are not important in this case, I believe.

The problem is that when I run it with an iterator, like

```py
for string in strings:
    output = model(string)
```

it seems to be working just fine (strings is a tf Dataset created from slices of 5x5), so it is a bunch of 5 by 5 matrices.

However when I pass over to training, or working at the dataset level with functions like predict, the model fails:

```py
model.predict(strings.batch(1))
```

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 5, 5, 6)
```

As far as I understand from documentation, the bidirectional layer takes 3d tensor as an input: [batch, timesteps, feature], so in this case my input shape should look like: [batch_size,timesteps,(5,5,6)]

So the question is which transformation should I apply to the input data to get this kind of shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Bidirectional input layer if you are using GRU, use `return_sequences=True`, to get 3-Dimension output. Since GRU output is 2D, return_sequences will give you 3D output. For stacked Bidirectional layer input should be of shape 3D.

**Sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(
    layers.Bidirectional(layers.GRU(64, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(5, 10))
)
model.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.GRU(32)))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

model.summary()
```

**Output**

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bidirectional_3 (Bidirection (None, 5, 128)            38400     
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_4 (Bidirection (None, 64)                41216     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 80,266
Trainable params: 80,266
Non-trainable params: 0
___________________________
```